# Make page numbers alternate between the right and the left corner when using apa.cls

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, templates, double-sided

I'm using the `apa.cls` (with the `doc`-style option) to typeset my document. This puts the number of each page in the top right corner. However, I'm going to print this document so I would like every *odd* page number to show up in the top right corner while every *even* page number to show up in the top left corner.

Minimal working example (where each page number shows up in the top right corner):

```
\documentclass[12pt, doc, noapacite]{apa}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\mbox{}
\newpage
\mbox{}
\newpage
\mbox{}
\newpage
\mbox{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `twoside` class option.

```
\documentclass[12pt,doc,noapacite,twoside]{apa}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\mbox{}
\newpage
\mbox{}
\newpage
\mbox{}
\newpage
\mbox{}
\end{document}
```